# matlab plot histogram indicating sum of each character inside a file

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have 400 files, each one contains about 500000 character, and those 500000 characters consists only from about 20 letters. I want to make a histogram indicating the most 10 letters used (x-axis) and number  of times each letter is used (y-axis). how can i make it.

Comment: Don't you know in advance what those 10 letters will be?

Comment: no, the letters are not known @LuisMendo

Comment: Then you can't use `hist`, because it assumes equal bin width. Try for example `h = hist([1 2 2 10], 3)`: wrong result

Comment: Your edit completely changes the question! As beaker said, "the most 10 popular characters" is very different from "consists only from 10 letters"

Answer (score 3):

Since you have an array of `uchar`, you know that your elements will always be in the range `0:255`. After seeing Tamás Szabó's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30812596/1377097) I realized that the null character is exceedingly unlikely in a text file, so I will just ignore it and use the range `1:255`. If you expect to have null characters, you'll have to adjust the range.

In order to find the 10 most frequently-used letters, we'll first calculate the histogram counts, then sort them in descending order and take the first 10:

```
counts = histc(uint8(part), [1:255]);
[topCounts, topIndices] = sort(counts, 'descend');
```

Now we need to rearrange the counts and indices to put the letters back in alphabetical order:

```
[sortedChars, shortIndices] = sort(topIndices(1:10));
sortedCounts = topCounts(shortIndices);
```

Now we can plot the histogram using `bar`:

```
bar(sortedCounts);
```

(You can add the `'hist'` option if you want the bars in the graph touching like they do in the normal `hist` plot.)

To change the horizontal legend from numeric values to characters, use `sortedChars` as the `'XtickLabel'`:

```
labelChars = cellstr(sortedChars.').';
set(gca, 'XtickLabel', labelChars);
```

Comment: Or `[~, used_bins, counts] = find(h);`

Comment: @LuisMendo That seems very handy.

Comment: @LuisMendo Unfortunately I had a one-off error due to the zero-based range and the one-based indices. I think we're back to two lines again.

Comment: @syd26 You would likely need to convert the array to a character array like `used_letters = char(used_letters)`.

Comment: @syd26 If you just want the graph, you can use `bar` on the results. Note that "the most 10 popular characters" is very different from "consists only from 10 letters" as stated in your question.

Comment: Totally agree, @beaker: it's very different. Sadly, the OP has edited the question. The problem is completely different now!

Comment: @LuisMendo And a duplicate. Nice.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This answers the *original version* of the question (the data consists of 10 letters only; a histogram is wanted). The question was *completely changed* (the data consists of about 20 letters, and a histogram of the 10 most used letters is wanted).

---

If the ten letters are arbitrary and not known in advance, you can't use `hist(..., 10)`. Consider the following example with three arbitrary "letters":

```
h = hist([1 2 2 10], 3);
```

The result is not `[1 2 1]` as you would expect. The problem is that `hist` chooses *equal-width* bins.

Here are three approaches to do what you want:

1. You can find the letters with [`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and then do the sum with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

   ```
   letters = unique(part(:)).';             %'// these are the letters in your file
   h = sum(bsxfun(@eq, part(:), letters));   %// count occurrences of each letter
   ```
2. The second line of the above approach could be replaced by [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html) specifying the bin edges:

   ```
   letters = unique(part(:)).';
   h = histc(part, letters);
   ```
3. Or you could use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) to do the accumulation:

   ```
   t = sparse(1, part, 1);
   [~, letters, h] = find(t);
   ```

As an example, for `part = [1 2 2 10]` either of the above gives the expected result,

```
letters =
     1     2    10
h =
     1     2     1
```

Comment: If you set `letters` to `[0:255]` you won't have to calculate `unique` first. Then `find` will give you the 10 populated bins.

Comment: @beaker But that's probably slower, as you will be computing the count for 245 letters that never occur

Comment: You never compute a count for a letter that doesn't occur. Histograms only count elements that are in the input array. And I'd rather do `find` on a 256-element array than `unique` on a 10000000 element array.